# Can not type in edittext android due to associated arraylist

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have an edittext with textwatcher

```
   selectedValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!selectedAssetType.equals(OrderBookTypes.MUTUAL_FUND_TYPE)) {
                    loadSearchFilterData();
                }
            }
        });
```

Here loadSearchFilterData() is as follows

```
private void loadSearchFilterData() {

    if (!selectedValue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        String s = selectedValue.getText().toString();
        List<BoOrderBookDao> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedFilteredList.size(); i++) {
            if (sortedFilteredList.get(i).getDpVal().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
                filterList.add(sortedFilteredList.get(i));
            }
        }
        orderBookModel.clear();
        orderBookModel.addAll(filterList);
    } else {
        orderBookModel.clear();
        orderBookModel.addAll(sortedFilteredList);
    }

    if (orderBookModel.size() == 0) {
        setErrorMsg(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_data_available_txt));
    } else {
        itemListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        errorScrollview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (orderAdapter != null) {
        orderAdapter.requestType = requestType;
        orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But now typing in edittext does not work. If I comment  `orderBookModel.addAll(sortedFilteredList);`
this line then it works